# What is the meaning of having ^ over a vector name?

Tags: notation, vectors

What is the usual meaning of having the symbol $\hat{}$ (i.e., a hat) over a vector name? What do vectors denoted by $\hat{\mathbf{u}}$ usually represent?

For example, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JK-8XNIoAkI), at min 3:00, the author denotes a unit vector by $\hat{\mathbf{u}}$, but I don't understand why not simply denoting it by $\mathbf{u}$. What is the difference between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{u}}$?

Comment: To denote a symbol with that "^" is to emphasize that the symbol represent a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @hkmather802: not really -- in my experience, that is the use of the arrow $\vec{}$ (conveniently, the \vec{} symbol in $\LaTeX$).

Comment: You got the answer for this situation and this should be good in your context. But another convention  is that when there is a list of vectors $e_1, \dots, e_n$ then $e_1, \dots, \hat{e_i}, \dots e_n$ should mean that $e_i$ is **omitted.** So it is something like short for   $e_1, \dots, e_{i-1},e_{i+1} \dots e_n$.// By the way tp type it here use `$\hat{v}$`

Comment: @ClementC. There's more than one way to write the same thing. other authors use boldface to indicate vectors. Or underlines. Or overlines.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I agree, conventions vary. Yet, the comment I answered to did miss the meaning of the $\hat{}$ in the linked video (if you watch it, you'll notice that vectors are denoted with an arrow, and that the hat is specifically for *unit* vectors).

Comment: @ClementC. Oh, OK. I would have said "In the video" rather than "In my experience" to convey that information! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $u$ is a mathematical object expressions like $\bar u$, $\hat u$, $\breve u$, $u'$, etc. usually denote **new** objects derived from $u$, or related to $u$, in some way, e.g.,
$$\breve f(x):=f(-x)\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
whereby the exact meaning is not an ISO standard, but is explained in the context. The overbar can denote the complex conjugate,  in other circumstances a mean value, or new coordinate functions $(\bar x_1,\ldots,\bar x_n)$ replacing the present $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Contrasting this, the notation $\vec{u}$ just tells the reader that the object $u$ is a **vector**. In a time where the number of usable fonts is unlimited one may as well write ${\bf u}$ right from the start, if one wishes to make the distinction between scalars and vectors visible at first glance. But $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is perfectly okay.

Given all this, the notation $\hat a$ leads to the following interpretations: It can mean (i) "I'm now introducing the vector $\hat a$, assumed to be a unit vector", or (ii) "Given any vector $a\ne0$ the vector $\hat a$ is defined by 
$$\hat a:={a\over\|a\|}\ .{\rm"}$$

Comment: There's no need for a previously defined vector $a$: $\hat{a}$ simply means that  $\hat{a}$ _is_ a unit vector. This notation is quite common in physics books, where typically the a is also typeset in bold: $\hat{\textbf{a}}$.

Comment: Your last paragraph is unclear. Contextually, there is no ambiguity about what $\hat a$ means. Every unit vector needs a circumflex (often called a hat) or an explanation. Any (finite, non-zero) vector may be normalized to length 1 by the procedure you've described, and any such vector is a unit vector by definition (also as you described). Change the last paragraph to read '$\hat{a}$ is a unit vector which is normalized to' [equation] for clarity.

Comment: Another example: a least squares solution of $\small Ax=b$ is a solution $\small \widehat {x}$ of $\small Ax = b_{Col(A)}$ ([source](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/least-squares.html))

Answer (score 12):

In the video, at that very time, the speaker explains he is using that notation to point out $\hat{u}$ is a unit vector, i.e. a vector of norm $1$.

This sort of notations (once explained) helps remembering what are the specific properties of the quantities used in a proof. (Just looking at $\hat{u}$, you know it is unit.)

In linear algebra, the $\hat{}$ is widely used for [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), so this is a general convention, at least in a good part of the world.

Comment: hat for a unit vector is pretty standard - many linear algebra and physics books use it.

Comment: @Batman: [apparently, indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (I've never seen it in my undergrad or grad classes, but this was in France.)

Answer (score 3):

If $\pmb u\in\Bbb R^n$ is any nonzero vector, then$$\hat{\pmb u}:=\frac{\pmb u}{\|\pmb u\|},$$where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the euclidean norm: $$\|\pmb u\|=\|(u_1,...,u_n)\|:=(u_1^2+\cdots+u_n^2)^\frac12.$$

As an example, take $n=3$ and $\pmb u=(4,0,3).$ Then $\|\pmb u\|=\sqrt{4^2+0^2+3^2}$ and $\hat{\pmb u}=(0.8,0,0.6).$

Answer (score 2):

In the video you linked $\hat{u}$ represents the unit vector. A lot of times you will see the unit vectors in the $x,y,z$ direction written like this.$$\hat{i}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\hat{j}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\hat{k}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Notice that this is just a convention. Here in Germany the unit vectors are written like this:

$$e_x, e_y,e_z\space \space \text{or} \space \space e_1,e_2,e_3 \space \space \text{or} \space \space \hat{e}_1,\hat{e}_2,\hat{e}_3$$