# Why is overhat notation used both for a unit vector, $\hat{x}$, and for the closest vector, $\hat{x}$, in the best approximation theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, approximation-theory

vector notation - why  is overhat notation used both for a unit vector, $\hat{\mathbf x} = {\mathbf x \over || \mathbf x ||}$, and for the closest vector in a subspace $\hat{\mathbf x}$ to a vector $\mathbf x$, related to the best approximation theorem in linear algebra.

I know that notation is developed by many people over time and confusing notation arises, but I am wondering if there is any rationale or reason or preference for one of these uses of the 'over hat' compared to the other.

looked at related question 
[What's the meaning of having ^ over a vector name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309362/whats-the-meaning-of-having-over-a-vector-name?rq=1)
but it does not answer this point as it does not refer to the use of the closest approximation vector.

Comment: There is no reason. It's just a case where we are using the same notation for different things. We run out of symbols so we have to re-use them.

Comment: @littleO - ok - many thanks for helpful comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a coincidence. There are just a few ways to mark a mathematical object as related to or sort of like one you have. You can write $x'$ or $\hat x$ or $\bar x$ or $x^*$ and a few others. Mathematicians in unrelated parts of the subject have chosen meanings for these annotations they find useful. Since there are more areas than markings there's bound to be some overlap.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, it is helpful to hear that. Just made me nervous as unit or normalized vectors and closest vectors both come up in linear algebra - wondering, for example, if people who were really into linear algebra had a different way of representing unit vectors.